# Extending a table (one to one relationship)

Tags: mysql, database-design, one-to-one

I have a `Users` table that belongs to a `Role`, and has one `Server` or no one (depends on role), but should to have a `Server` table with `user_id` field or should I put all Server info in Users table and when the role hasn't Servers, the fields will be null?

I just think that if a User have one server (or not), this shouldn't be a new row in Servers table, maybe if the user_id field be unique, then it will be correct, I don't know.. I'm confused.

Just explain to me which is the best way to build this thing.

-- edit

This is my tables actually

`Roles`

```
id (PK) | name
1       | Administrator
```

`Users`

```
   id (PK) | role_id | name
   1       | 1       | Juliano
```

`Servers`

```
   id (PK) | user_id (UNIQUE) | name
   1       | 1                | Test
```

I don't know.. in servers, user_id should be UNIQUE or PK?

Answer (score 0):

ONE TO ONE Relation ,  Then put the server in the user table.

```
Users Table:
 ID(Pk)
 RoleID
 Name
 ServerID
```

Comment: Really? if he doesn't have a server, ServerID will be null, right? and if I want to know who owns the server? and in this case a Server can belong to more than one user.. then your logic goes right?

Comment: If you don't need the server table, Change the ServerID to Server, and remove the table Server. you get one to one relationship. Yes, the server field will be null if he doesn't have a server. you can querry using the server info or the user info to know who owns the server. To prevent a server owned by 2 user, u need to check the server ownership first before giving the server ownership to a user.

Comment: Isn't easier in the way that is in my question?

Comment: Probably. you're the man (developer). so use it the most suitable method for you, as long as you get what u want.